# How to implement css from w3 to Shiny Application

Tags: css, r, shiny

I tried to use css from w3 for my Shiny app. Based on their code

```
<div class="w3-display-container w3-text-white">
  <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">Middle</div>
</div>
```

I defined `style.css` in UI

```
# style.css
.w3-display-container {
   position:relative
}

.w3-display-middle {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.w3-text-white:hover{color:#fff}

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
   navbarPage("",
     tabPanel("Home",
       fluidRow(column(12,
          tags$div(class = ".w3-display-container",
               img(src = "homepage9.jpg",width="100%", height = 400,
                  tags$div(class= ".w3-display-middle", p("Data"))))))))))
```

I don't know how to use tags$div correct if there are so many div in div.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I get the scenario right: you have one file `style.css` and another file like `app.R` with your actual application. You want to embed the style and emulate the HTML on the very top.

I see two points that might help you here:

1.) you have to link to the style - maybe by including a `link` tag pointing to it (or creating a `style` tag with the style inline - I'd start with the latter). The following code is a little on the nose, but it works:

```
shinyApp(ui=verticalLayout(tag("style", "body {background: pink; }")), server=function(input, output){})
```

2.) I think you have one error in the HTML: `img` has no children, so you might want to re-write the last part of your code like this:

```
ags$div(class = ".w3-display-container",
  img(src = "homepage9.jpg",width="100%", height = 400),
  tags$div(class= ".w3-display-middle", p("Data"))
```